# htaccess help needed

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the http:mydomain.com to http//www.mydomain.com. 
Also I need to include one more condition

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|uploads|editor|albums|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And I have redirect code as

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

How to combine these two in a single htaccess file?

-Arun

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste them together in one `.htaccess` file should be enough. There's no reason those two are not able to be together in one `.htaccess`. You should have the www one run first though:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|uploads|editor|albums|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: When I try both, it shows an Internal Server Error. If I comment second two rules, redirection will work, but I need both conditions else my folders goes public.

Answer (score 0):

Litso's answer looks right to me but try this anyway..

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|images|css|uploads|editor|albums|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

I've replaced $! in the second condition and removed the redundant ^$ anchors from the rules.